# adding columns to a file with same number of rows

Tags: paste

I have a file like this naming it as file1

```
chr1    24018319    +   a
chr1    24019249    +   b
chr1    24020403    +   c
chr1    24021281    +   d
chr1    24022398    +   e
chr1    45241272    +   f
chr1    45241812    +   g
chr1    45242446    +   h
chr1    45243461    +   I
chr1    45243801    +   j
```

I have some other input files as well. They look like this:

```
chr1    24018319    0   +
chr1    24019249    22.4309 +
chr1    24020403    64.302  +
chr1    24021281    20.9355 +
chr1    24022398    32.8987 +
chr1    45241272    1.49539 +
chr1    45241812    318.519 +
chr1    45242446    207.86  +
chr1    45243461    112.155 +
chr1    45243801    67.2927 +
```

These other files have same number of rows as compared to the first file, file1.

I want to add 3rd column of every such file to the first file1(since the rows are equal) and I tried paste command but it didn't work.

I want the output like this:

```
chr1    24018319    +   a   0
chr1    24019249    +   b   22.4309
chr1    24020403    +   c   64.302
chr1    24021281    +   d   20.9355
chr1    24022398    +   e   32.8987
chr1    45241272    +   f   1.49539
chr1    45241812    +   g   318.519
chr1    45242446    +   h   207.86
chr1    45243461    +   I   112.155
chr1    45243801    +   j   67.2927
```

How can I do it. I tried this

```
paste -d "\t" file $(cut -f 3 file2) $(cut -f 3 file3)
```

but this didn't work

Thanks

Comment: This works!! Thanks
I am getting confused with command substitution and process substitution. Will read again

Answer (score 0):

The command below generates the output you request in your example to some extent, although doesnt preserve the spaces.

```
$ join -j 2 -o 1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 2.3 file1 file2
chr1 24018319 + a 0
chr1 24019249 + b 22.4309
chr1 24020403 + c 64.302
chr1 24021281 + d 20.9355
chr1 24022398 + e 32.8987
chr1 45241272 + f 1.49539
chr1 45241812 + g 318.519
chr1 45242446 + h 207.86
chr1 45243461 + I 112.155
chr1 45243801 + j 67.2927
$
```